# React custom hook returned function doesn't have updated value of the parent scope variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have defined below custom hook in the utils file

```
//utils.js
export function useUniqNameValidator() {
    const nameList = useSelector(accountDetailsSelector);
    return (value) => {
        return nameList
        .every((item) => value !== item.name));
    };
}
```

and I am importing it in a main component

```
import { useUniqNameValidator } from './utils.js'
.
.
.
const uniqValidator = useUniqNameValidator()
.
.
.
return (
  <ChildComponent uniqValidator={uniqValidator}  />
)
```

and I am using it inside a child component inside a function

```
handleAdd(name){
   if(props.uniqValidator(name)){
      console.log('Name already exist')
   }else{
     // code to add the name to accountDetails
   }
}
```

The returned function from the useUniqNameValidator doesn't have the updated values of nameList. On initial render only it is having the updated value, on rerenders, the returned function uses the old values of nameList, I tried using useCallback also but it doesn't help, I am not sure how to get the updated value of nameList, whenever I am calling the handleAdd function

Answer (score 0):

You have called a useSelector hook inside a custom hook. This is against the pattern described by hooks.
You can try calling the `const nameList = useSelector(accountDetailsSelector);` at the top of a component and then passing down the value to the hook. [Refer this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

```
const MyComp: FC<Props> = props => {
...
const nameList = useSelector(accountDetailsSelector);
const uniqValidator = useUniqNameValidator(nameList);
return (
  <ChildComponent uniqValidator={uniqValidator}  />
)
...
}
```

Please alter the logic as it may fit

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. can you pls share the link to the docs suggesting that we should not use useSelector inside the hook? because I am not getting any error or warning regarding that

Comment: by the paradigm, i guess the issue is more related with persistence since the data is being passed down as a prop and the useSelector is not invoked each time there is an update. you can also try calling the `useSelector(...)` in the child component. 
Just a thought :)

Comment: it'd be good it we have some codesandbox or something to reproduce this issue

Comment: due to security reasons, i can't post the actual code, the issue is in the returned function, it is not updating the value,